# Why does shell command “{ command1; command2: } &" open a subshell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, subshell

As we all know, placing a list of commands between curly braces causes the list to be executed in the current shell context. No subshell is created. But when using "&" after "{}", why two subshells are created? pid 1002 and 1003.

```
{
    ./a.out
} &

sleep 19
```

[image]

when using "./a.out &", only a subshell is created. pid 17358.

```
./a.out &
sleep 19
```

[image]

Why ?

Comment: Did you mean to say "when using "./a.out &", a subshell is NOT created"?

Comment: only a subshell is created. pid is 17358. But, "{ ./a.out } &", two subshells are created. pid 1003 and 1002.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Background execution of a list uses a subshell because something needs to wait for each member of that list and run the next one. After a list is backgrounded, the parent shell needs to be available for new commands; it can't manage the backgrounded list too. bash can't do more than one thing at a time. So, to make the backgrounded list work, it runs a subshell.

Note that you can disown a backgrounded list and it will keep running, showing that the subshell is doing its work:

```
$ {
> sleep 1; sleep 2; sleep 3; sleep 4; sleep 5
> } &
$ disown
$ ps -f | grep sleep
dave     31845 31842  0 03:50 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 3 
dave     31849 31771  0 03:50 pts/1    00:00:00 grep sleep
```

You could even log out and the subshell would continue running processes in the list.

When you background a single command, there is no need for a subshell because there is no more work for the shell to do after it has run the command.

In your example, the second additional bash subprocess, PID 1002, appears to be a script which you're executing. That's unrelated (conceptually, at least) to the list-backgrounding mechanism; any script in a separate file has its own bash process.

Comment: Dave, thanks. But I don't know why commond ”{ ./a.out } &" causes two subshell created?

Comment: It doesn't; it only creates one additional shell (PID 1003 in your example) to manage the pipeline. In your example, PID 1002 seems to be a script that contains "{ ./a.out } &", which is its own shell for a different reason.

Comment: using shell (PID 1003) to manage the pipeline? Can you explain in detail, please

Comment: That's what I explained in my answer: the subshell waits for each command to finish and starts the next. I shouldn't really have said "pipeline", though, since the commands aren't piped one to the next. It's a sequence of separate commands.

Comment: Dave, I've figured out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell executes the command (or list of commands that are enclosed in `{...}`) in the **background** (or asynchronously) in a **subshell**.

The shell does not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

In C program it is done by doing a `fork()` followed by `execvp()` system calls.

---

**Update:** Based on comments below and updated question. Here is what is happening.

When you run:

```
./a.out &
```

BASH directly just runs `a.out` in background as running binary `a.out` doesn't need a separate shell process.

When you run:

```
{ ./a.out; } &
```

BASH must first fork and create a subshell as you can have series of commands inside `{...}` and then the newly forked subshell runs `a.out` in a separate process. So it is not that BASH is creating 2 subshells for this. Only one subshell gets created and 2nd pid you're seeing is for `a.out`.

Comment: But Only a subshell is created when using "./a.out &".  while, "{ ./a.out } &" cases the command  executed in the subshell's subshell.

Comment: `&` in front of any command will make that command run in a sub-shell

Comment: a.out `int main() { sleep(100); return 0; }`